# preposition and articles

Tags: prepositions, articles

I read the following sentence in an online article:
'It means that every new word or terminology can be added in the database of online dictionary.'
I just wonder why not 'added to' instead of 'added in' because in the Oxford dictionary I cannot find any other preposition after 'add' besides preposition 'to'. Moreover, is it correct to use 'online dictionary' alone? Or it should be 'an online dictionary' or 'the online dictionary' or 'online dictionaries'? 
Please help me. Many thanks.

Comment: Yes; if you 'add something in', it's a paraphrase of 'add in something'. 'We added in the tomatoes / We added the tomatoes in'. This is an incorrect usage. 'To' (or 'into') is required. // Almost certainly 'an' or 'the' (or 'any', ...) is required. Online articles vary in grammaticality.

Comment: So the grammatically correct sentence should be ''It means that every new word or terminology can be added to the database of any online dictionary''. Thank you very much!